# Quickly read all sliding windows of large GeoTIFF

Tags: python, gdal, digital-image-processing

I'm currently using python and gdal to read sliding windows of a given size across very large 3-4 band (RGB/RGBA) GeoTIFFs with a nested for loop and `gdal.Translate()` to grab the data in a given window. Is there a faster way to accomplish this while maintaining the geotransform of pixels within the windows? I need to maintain the geotransform of a given window to do some subsequent processing of vector data within that window after doing some array operations on the pixels within a window itself. Below is what I'm currently doing, its pretty quick but wondering if there is a better optimized solution:

```
import os
import numpy as np
from affine import Affine
from osgeo import gdal

src = 'path.tif'

image = gdal.Open(os.path.abspath(src))
width = int(image.RasterXSize)
height = int(image.RasterYSize)

tile_size = 512
stride = 0

for i in range(0, width, int(tile_size * (1 - stride))):
    for j in range(0, height, int(tile_size * (1 - stride))):
        srcWin = [i, j, tile_size, tile_size]

        in_mem = f"/vsimem/in_memory_{i}_{j}.tif"

        window = gdal.Translate(in_mem, image, srcWin=srcWin)
        arr = window.ReadAsArray()

        gdal.Unlink(in_mem)

        """do some operations on the image array"""

        affine_transform = Affine.from_gdal(*eval(str(window.GetGeoTransform())))

        """do some things to pandas DataFrame"""

        window = None
        arr = None
```

Comment: Why aren't you reading the GDAL dataset directly? Calculate your offsets and dimension from srcWin relative to the geotransform of your source image then use those values to read image.ReadAsArray(), you'll get the same answer quicker.

Comment: To be honest, I’m not sure. When I was first coming up with this gdal.Translate() with the source window was what I found and it worked so I hadn’t tried passing the window directly into ReadAsArray(). But what you’re saying makes total sense.

Comment: I have some code performing a similar operation, would you be interested in that?

Comment: If using image.ReadAsArray() with the offsets works then I should have it from here but if you'd like to post it I'll mark it as the accepted answer and close out this, now looking back, rather simple question

Comment: So I implemented what was needed to get image.ReadAsArray() with offsets to function properly with the rest of my code and the total time was the same as using gdal.Translate() then ReadAsArray(), which I found very surprising. The direct read with offset was ~10% faster than gdal translate but something else got 10% slower unfortunately…

Comment: @mrgeo, it is generally faster to read the whole array into memory (if it fits in memory ) and then apply the processing because this reduces the amount of IO to disk operations. However, this will also depend on the hardware since a new m.2 SSD will IO a lot faster than a HDD. Have a look a the PC/server resource monitor to get an idea of where the bottleneck is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directly reading the raster is the fastest method. Here is a snippet of code I use to combine a folder of rasters, not really a mosaic operation, it's an addition operation, similar to [Esri Cell Statistics](https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z0000007q000000) without using ArcGIS and Spatial Analyst. 1000 GeoTIFF files (pixel dimensions 1000 x 1000) combine in less than 5 seconds.

```
# start with the GeoTransform which defines location and cell size
# then calculate the pixel width/height and create the raster with
# the correct rows/columns, band count and data type; the
# GeoTransform is set immediately after creation.
MosaicGT      = [int(WorkingExtent['Xmin']-(5*CellSize)),CellSize,0,
                                int(WorkingExtent['Ymax']+(5*CellSize)),0,-CellSize]
MosaicWidth   = int((WorkingExtent['Xmax'] - WorkingExtent['Xmin'])/CellSize)
MosaicHeight  = int((WorkingExtent['Ymax'] - WorkingExtent['Ymin'])/CellSize)
MosaicWidth  += 10
MosaicHeight += 10
Driver        = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTIFF')
MosaicDataset = Driver.Create(OutRaster,MosaicWidth,MosaicHeight,1,gdal.GDT_Float32)
MosaicBand    = MosaicDataset.GetRasterBand(1)

MosaicDataset.SetGeoTransform(MosaicGT)
MosaicBand.Fill(0.0)           # fill with zeros
MosaicBand.FlushCache()        # and make sure it's written to the file
MosaicBand.SetNoDataValue(0.0) # set the NoData to zero
# note that setting the NoData value has no meaning for read/write in GDAL
# the cell value will always be fetched/written regardless. It's just handy
# to use 0 for NoData as the raster is 0 initialized so that I don't need
# to use logic when summing the values.

# loop through the intermediate files, calculate the offset, rows and columns for the mosaic
# based on the intermediate file extent then read that as a numpy array
for ThisRaster in InterFiles:
    ThisDS    = gdal.Open(ThisRaster,gdal.GA_ReadOnly)
    ThisGT    = ThisDS.GetGeoTransform()
    ThisRows  = ThisDS.RasterYSize
    ThisCols  = ThisDS.RasterXSize
    OffsetX   = int((ThisGT[0]-MosaicGT[0])/CellSize)
    OffsetY   = int((MosaicGT[3]-ThisGT[3])/CellSize)
    ThisBit   = ThisDS.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray(0,0,ThisCols,ThisRows)
    MosaicBit = MosaicBand.ReadAsArray(OffsetX,OffsetY,ThisCols,ThisRows)
    MosaicBand.WriteArray( numpy.add(MosaicBit,ThisBit),OffsetX,OffsetY)
    ThisDS = None # Close the raster properly
```